# How to set columns of "ForEach" next to eachOthers

Tags: swift, swiftui, foreach

I'm trying to put some data from "ForEach" side by side but I don't know how to do it in a right way...

This is what've got

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var vm = notaViewModel()
    
    @State var puntajeMaximo: String
    @State var notaMaxima: String
    @State var notaMinima: String
    @State var notaAprobacion: String
    @State var notaExigencia: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            
            // puntajeMaximo = Maximun score you can get
            ForEach(0...vm.puntajeMaximo, id: \.self) { score in
                
                HStack {
                    
                    if vm.puntajeMaximo / 2 >= score {
                        Text("\(score) -> \(vm.getAverage(puntos: Float(score)))")
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                            .background(Color("textFieldBackground"))
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                    
                    if vm.puntajeMaximo / 2 < score {
                        
                        Text("\(score) -> \(vm.getAverage(puntos: Float(score)))")
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                            .background(Color("textFieldBackground"))
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                        
                }
                
                
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            vm.setParameters(pMax: puntajeMaximo, nMaxima: notaMaxima, nMinima: notaMinima, nAprobacion: notaAprobacion, nExigencia: notaExigencia)
        }
        
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(puntajeMaximo: "30", notaMaxima: "70", notaMinima: "10", notaAprobacion: "40", notaExigencia: "60")
    }
}
```

[image: 1]

As you can see, I have a column with numbers (score) from 0 to 30 and a Float next to it, the first 15 are red and I need them to be at the left and the others, from 15 to 30 to be at the right. I've been trying with HStack, Vstack, Grid and cannot get the answer

Please help, this is driving me crazy

Comment: have a look at this question hope this will solve your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71732681/swiftui-foreach-index-jump-by-2

Answer (score 0):

**1. Why you have taken String instead of Number when you need to compare the value.**

**2. We have two different way which I have shared below from which 2 one is appropriate answer according to me still you can choose any one as per your requirement.**

> **ANSWER 1**

```
var body: some View {
        HStack{
            VStack{
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                    ForEach(0...puntajeMaximo, id: \.self) { score in
                        HStack {
                            if puntajeMaximo / 2 >= score {
                                Text("\(score) -> \(score).\(score)")
                                    .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                                    .background(.white)
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 100)
                .background(Color.orange)
            VStack{
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(0...puntajeMaximo, id: \.self) { score in
                        HStack {
                            if puntajeMaximo / 2 < score {

                                Text("\(score) -> \(score).\(score)")
                                    .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                                    .background(.white)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                .background(Color.yellow)
        }

}
```

[Answer 1 Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbGdZ.png)
Here you can check scroll hidden and some other difference in two scrollview

> ANSWER 2 (Preferred)

```
// Need to create Item in List which requires to conform Identifiable protocol
struct ListItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let score: Int
}

struct ContentViews: View {
    
//    @StateObject private var vm = notaViewModel()
    @State var puntajeMaximo: Int
    
    init(puntajeMaximo: Int) {
        self.puntajeMaximo = puntajeMaximo
        
        getData()
    }
    
    var leftData: [ListItem] = []
    var rightData: [ListItem] = []
    
    var body: some View {
            HStack{
                VStack{
                    List(leftData) { data in
                        Text("\(data.score) -> \(data.score).\(data.score)")
                                        .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                                        .background(.gray.opacity(0.3))
                                        .cornerRadius(10)
                                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                                        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                    }
                }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 100)
                    .background(Color.orange)
                
                VStack{
                    List(rightData) { data in
                        Text("\(data.score) -> \(data.score).\(data.score)")
                                        .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                                        .background(.gray.opacity(0.3))
                                        .cornerRadius(10)
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
            }
    }
    
// Must be called in init or before rendering the view 
    mutating func getData() {
        for score in 0...puntajeMaximo {
            if (puntajeMaximo / 2 >= score) {
                leftData.append(ListItem(score: score))
            } else if puntajeMaximo / 2 < score {
                rightData.append(ListItem(score: score))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentViews_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentViews(puntajeMaximo: 30)
    }
}
```

[Answer 2 Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEmfE.png)

**Required**

1. A mutating method that separates the list for left and right view
2. A struct that conforms Identifiable protocol to pass in ListView as a row.
3. You can make changes to design as per you requirement.
4. As this method runs loop only 1 time and separates the list instead of Answer 1 which runs loop twice for both view